# Normal distribution of 10 values

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, independence

Given are $10$ independently identically distributed values $X_1,..X_{10}$ with a normal distribution $N(5, 10)$.

What is the correct distrbiution for $X'=\frac{1}{10}*\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i$

I think $\mu$ should always stay the same, so it should remain $5$. As we only have $10$ values and they get divided by $10$ I guess that $\sigma^{2}$ gets bigger, so that $X' \sim N(5, 100)$ will be the correct answer.
Does this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\text{Var}(X')=\frac{1}{100}\times\sum_{i=1}^{10} \text{Var}(X_i)=\frac{1}{100}\times10(10)=1
$$
since
$$
\text{Var}(cY)=c^2\text{Var}(Y)
$$
and the $X_i$ are independent.